# Navbar toggler no reaction issue

Tags: navbar

I have this navbar - everything works just fine, but one thing is wrong - on the mobile, when you see the navbar-toggler icon - you click it - navbar drops down and shows, but when you click again - no response. You need to click at least twice, sometimes more to close the dropdown menu again. Where is the issue? Thanks

```
<section id="nav">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-dnsa sticky-top">
<div class="container padding">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logoo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
       <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nás</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">DAS"DAL</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Formulář pro objednávku</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be fine, check if you included the CSS CDN in the head of your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and the bootstrap JS scripts just before the ending body tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="nav">
            <nav
                class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-dnsa sticky-top"
            >
                <div class="container padding">
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"
                        ><img src="img/logo.png" class="logoo"
                    /></a>
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
                        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div
                        class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                        id="navbarNavDropdown"
                    >
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nás</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">DAS"DAL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                                    >Formulář pro objednávku</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </section>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are not using CDN to get the CSS link and JS scripts into your HTML file, try to re-download and replace the CSS and JS folders.

If you still have trouble, I fear the problem is in your PC being too slow? That we may discuss after you check for the problems I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am using CDN, I havent got these scripts right before  tag, so I added them. But no change. I am 100% sure, that it has nothing to do with speed. Because I am testing it on my mobile, which is quite new.

One thing i have noticed - When I click 2 times, it quicky close and open, but still - when i click one time - nothing even when i wait.

Answer (score 0):

Now that's really funny, because on my notebook and mobiles everything works how it should... The code is definitely not wrong.

Let's analyze the problem - it has to be in the script tags that you are bringing in via CDN, because those are behind the collapsing behaviour (conretely the first one and the last one).

Check if those two script tags are exactly the same as here:
https://getbootstrap.com/ in the BootstrapCDN section.

If that doesn't work, then try to ditch CDN and download the compiled JS from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/

After you download the files, copy them into your project dir and include them via script tags with src attributes similarly as you would include the CDN.

If that doesn't work, it really has to be an inner problem which I cannot solve.